# How can i update a record of specfic user from start date of moth till the end of that specific month?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

[Database columns Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsMUM.png)

```
UPDATE `agentstats` SET `total_target` = '150' from `agentstats` Where `date` BETWEEN '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-31'and`user_id` = 3
```

```
user_id is the foreign key
```

This is the query i made its not working.
Can any one please help me this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors. Try this:

```
UPDATE `agentstats` 
SET `total_target` = '150'
Where `date` BETWEEN '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-31' and `user_id` = 3
```

Basically: remove `` from `agentstats` ``  and add spaces before and after the `and` in `` '2022-01-31'and`user_id` = 3 ``